# Can you compress the below data:[2016][04][03][13][35][00][14][125][2][1] into 8 bytes with given information?

Tags: compression, bit-manipulation, bit

We have 16 electrical switches that can be set to be switched on or off with a schedule sent to it through a bluetooth device. For example, I want to turn on switch with serial 14 on 3 April, 2016 at 1:35 PM. I also have to specify an alarm id(which can be 0 to 255) and type of alarm(once(0), daily(1), weekly(2), monthly(3), so there are 4 types).

So, for example, consider this schedule string:

> [2016][04][03][13][35][00][14][125][2][1]

Let's break this down:

```
2016 is the year
04 is the month(can be 1-12)
03 is the day(can be 1-31)
13 is the hour(can be 0-23)
35 is the minute(can be 0-59)
00 is the second(can be 0-59)
14 is the switch ID(can be 0-15)
125 is the alarm ID(can be 0-255)
2 is alarm type(can be 0-3)
1 is the command to switch on ( can only be 0 and 1, 0 is for off)
```

But, the bluetooth device can only carry 8 bytes at a time.The square brackets are for your visual guide only, you can ignore them.
To make the format clearer:

> [Year][Month][Day][Hour][Minute][Seconds][Switch ID(0-15)][Alarm
>   ID(0-255)][Alarm type(0-3)][Switch on or off(0-1)]

Comment: If you need to send it as a number, how about sacryficing the "20" from the year? Then it would fit into 8byte number easily - 1604031335001412521, plus I believe, that the seconds aren't crucial, so you can sacryfice them as well

Comment: @j.kaspar i am not sacrificing "20" from the year then how can i solve it . any idea  ..???

thnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this can be done with ease based upon the following :-

Switch 1 bit,

Alarm Type = 2 bits

Alarm Id - 8 bits

Switch ID = 4 bits

Seconds = 6 bits

Minutes = 6 bits

Hour = 5 bits

Day = 5 bits

Month = 4 bits

Year = plenty of scope with the remaining 23 bits, but specific enough requirements ie the range was not provided.

e.g. An unsigned variant of Packed decimal, 4 bits per numeric character, would only require 16 bits and would cater for the range 0-9999. This would probably well exceed any reasonable expectation.

This was accomplished by using the following :-

1 bit if max is 0-1

2 bits if max is 2-3

3 bits if max is 4-7

4 bits if max is 8-15

5 bits if max is 16-31

6 bits if max is 32-63

7 bits if max is 64-127

8 bits if max is 128-255 ........